# How Do I Parse XML Webpage In C++

Tags: c++, xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing

I've been searching the internet for an hour or so, and I surrender, how do I do it?

I just want to take a webpage with a simple xml output with something simple like the weather or stock information, and have it spit out something saying, "The temperature is 90f" or "google is up". For example, http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=New+York would say "It is 70f" or something like that.

I am extremely new to C++ and I don't know much about this, and if you are going to direct me to a library, could you please also **show me a tutorial on installing new libraries? I am using visual C++ 2010, and I can't seem to find how to install new libraries.**

Comment: What is "webpage with a simple xml output"?

Comment: Search for XML parsers. There are tons of them. Starting from MSXML (It works but I am not sure it is the best one).

Comment: Although for a web-page scraper I'd recommend an *HTML* parser.

Comment: "I am extremely new to C++" Then you shouldn't be doing this. The first thing you do in most languages is *not* accessing websites and parsing HTML for information. Personally, I'd suggest using something like Python if you want to try this sort of thing as a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two c++ libraries

for call the http resource
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

for parsing XML output
http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html

Look at documentation for information about their use

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Microsoft Xmlite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**. [A Small And Fast XML Parser For Native C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163436.aspx). other *Microsoft* solutions are:

- MSXML (SAX2) (native)
- System.XML.XmlReader (managed)